# Programmatically add class to UIbutton in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uibutton

I'm new to Swift and am confused as how to programmatically add a custom class to a button. I created a custom class and can add it using the storyboard. It works fine, but how would this be done programmatically?

[image]

Can I use the CheckBox class in place of UIButton or would I still need to use UIButton and add the class?

The Class

```
class CheckBox: UIButton {

//images
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox") //as UIImage!
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox") //as UIImage!

//bool property
var isChecked:Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if isChecked == true {
            self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }else {
            self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }

    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}


func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    if(sender == self){
        if isChecked == true {
            println("setting to false")
            isChecked = false
        }else{
             println("setting to true")
            isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

Adding the class to the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let checkBox = CheckBox()

    checkBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.view.addSubview(checkBox)

    checkBox.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkBox, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: checkBox, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50))


}
```

Comment: You can use your Checkbox class in place of UIButton within your code

Comment: @TienDinh Thanks! My problem must be with my class then or with the way I am adding the Checkbox class to the view controller. I updated the question to include the viewDidLoad and class. Am I missing something about the difference of how to add UIButton programmatically vs in the storyboard?

Comment: "My problem must be with my class then or with the way I am adding the Checkbox class to the view controller" But @Oakland510, you have not explained what your problem _is_! Does the checkbox not appear in the interface? What happens or fails to happen that is problematic?

Comment: @matt the checkbox does not appear. If I call checkbox.isCheck = true or false the checkbox appears but does not change if clicked. If I add the button via storyboard and set the custom class to CheckBox the checkbox appears and changes when clicked.

Comment: @matt even with checkBox.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 100) I'm still getting nothing. If I set checkBox.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor() I can at least get a blue box to appear that's the right size. However it is still not the checkbox that I am expecting.

Comment: But you have also forgotten to add your check box images to the button, haven't you? That is another thing that I guess you had set up in the storyboard but have forgotten to set up in your code? Without a title or an image, the button has no size.

Comment: @matt : Won't the `isChecked` setter method set the images in the button? The op uses `self.setImage:forState:` - shouldn't that do the job?

Comment: @aksh1t But he never sets `isChecked`.

Comment: He is setting `isChecked` in the `buttonClicked` method; but I see that it won't be getting called as the target will not be set. Gotcha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the checkbox does not appear

Could that be because you have forgotten to give your `checkbox` any *size*?

Also, I notice you have these images:

```
let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked_checkbox") //as UIImage!
let uncheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked_checkbox") //as UIImage!
```

But could it be that you have forgotten to put either of those images *in the button*? I don't see any code that does that.

> If I call `checkbox.isCheck = true` or `false` the checkbox appears but does not change if clicked

Could that be because you have forgotten to give your `checkbox` any target-action for its control event? Previously you had this code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
}
```

But now there is no `awakeFromNib` call - this button does not awake from a nib. The storyboard is the nib. This button is coming from code now.

If you fix that, so that that code is called, then `isChecked` will be set and the image will appear, won't it?

Comment: "The storyboard is the nib" would explain a lot. Setting the size doesn't seem to help. If I set the size and background color, I just get a button the color and size expected without the checkbox image. Is there a better function I could move the contents of awakeFromNib to?  I'm assuming I could move it to the viewDidLoad, but would rather keep it within the class itself.

Comment: You are saying `let checkBox = CheckBox()` so you are calling the CheckBox `init()` method. So that would presumably be a place to put that code that _will_ be called.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to do it programmatically(swift 2.2), and not via the storyboard, make sure you add an **override int** function, a **required init?** function, and put the following in your **override init**:

```
override init(frame: CGRect)
{
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckBox.ButtonClicked(_:)),      
    forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.isChecked = false
    self.setImage(uncheckedImage, forState: .Normal)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}
```

The important bit is the ***self.setImage***. I couldn't get the images to appear when the View loaded up.